# Netbeans is not picking up the correct release for a JAR dependency with jitpack

Tags: java, netbeans, github, jar, jitpack

This build file for the [client](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_client) specifies the `dev` release, using jitpack, of the [library](https://github.com/THUFIR/hello_api):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.mordor.hello.client.HelloClient'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
if (!hasProperty(mainClassName)) {
    ext.mainClass = mainClassName
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    compile 'com.github.THUFIR:hello_api:dev'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes ('Main-Class': mainClassName,
            "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
    }
}

assemble.dependsOn (jar)

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

yet Netbeans shows `hello_api-latest.jar` and not `hello_api-dev.jar` as it should:

[image]